# Accessory View image not highlighted when row selected

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have added an accessoryView `UIView` in my `UITableCell` when `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called.

```
cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flechalinterna.png"]];
cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

But when the user selects row at index path, the accessory view is not highlighted. I tried to avoid it setting the background color to `clearColor` but it does not make any difference. Getting the following effect shown in this image:

[image]

Comment: Does your `flechalinterna.png` has transparent background ?

Comment: I think you are right, will make my images transparent and will check again. Thank you

Comment: @graver it certainly works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one

```
cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flechalinterna.png"] highlightedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flechalinterna.png"]];
```

Comment: It has no difference, I think @graver is right about the transparent background. Will change my .png image